# Sending informaton to a sage pay payment gateway

Tags: iframe, payment-gateway, opayo, worldpay

I have product designer software in my website that currently allows customers to design a product and get a live price. The software has the ability to send a message to the parent of an iframe where the information can be processed as I like. I want this information to be sent to my sagepay, worldpay or stripe payment gateway to give the customers the ability of purchasing the product.

Does anyone have any idea how to achieve this or even where to start!

Thanks in advance
Dan

Comment: Is the part about messaging the parent frame already done, or is it part of the question? It's a little unclear from the current wording. Let me know if you change the wording and I'll delete this comment.

Answer (score 0):

Most payment gateways allow somehow to send the details of the purchased products details via API when processing the payment.

For SagePay (if you mean the one which currently is labeled as Opayo by Elavon) you may use the detailed basket via [XML](https://developer-eu.elavon.com/docs/opayo-forms/api-reference/basketxml) or [CSV](https://developer-eu.elavon.com/docs/opayo-forms/api-reference/basket). Or you may simply use the [common](https://developer-eu.elavon.com/docs/opayo-forms/api-reference/crypt-field) `Description` field.

For Worldpay it's the `instruction.narrative.line1` field from the [authorization request](https://developer.worldpay.com/docs/access-worldpay/payments/authorize-a-payment).

And for Stripe it should be either `metadata` or `payment_intent_data` [objects](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create).